# Adding extra text (second value) under bars in graph, without changing contents of table

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I'm trying to make a bar graph that shows the amount of calories of the food with the least amount of calories for each food category in my csv file. I've succeeded in doing this, but in my bar graph, I'm supposed to show both the food category and the name of the food under the bars,
[like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyfKX.png) Currently, I only have the name of the food category under teh bars, [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5lNr.png)

my current code:

```
Ams3 = data.groupby('Category',).Calories.min()
Ams3.plot.bar()
```

my data.head().to_dict():

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
 'Category': {0: 'Breakfast',
  1: 'Breakfast',
  2: 'Breakfast',
  3: 'Breakfast',
  4: 'Breakfast'},
 'Item': {0: 'Egg McMuffin',
  1: 'Egg White Delight',
  2: 'Sausage McMuffin',
  3: 'Sausage McMuffin with Egg',
  4: 'Sausage McMuffin with Egg Whites'},
 'Serving Size': {0: '4.8 oz (136 g)',
  1: '4.8 oz (135 g)',
  2: '3.9 oz (111 g)',
  3: '5.7 oz (161 g)',
  4: '5.7 oz (161 g)'},
 'Calories': {0: 300.0, 1: 250.0, 2: 370.0, 3: 450.0, 4: 400.0},
 'Calories from Fat': {0: 120, 1: 70, 2: 200, 3: 250, 4: 210},
 'Total Fat': {0: 13.0, 1: 8.0, 2: 23.0, 3: 28.0, 4: 23.0},
 'Total Fat (% Daily Value)': {0: 20, 1: 12, 2: 35, 3: 43, 4: 35},
 'Saturated Fat': {0: 5.0, 1: 3.0, 2: 8.0, 3: 10.0, 4: 8.0},
 'Saturated Fat (% Daily Value)': {0: 25, 1: 15, 2: 42, 3: 52, 4: 42},
 'Trans Fat': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0, 4: 0.0},
 'Cholesterol': {0: 260, 1: 25, 2: 45, 3: 285, 4: 50},
 'Cholesterol (% Daily Value)': {0: 87, 1: 8, 2: 15, 3: 95, 4: 16},
 'Sodium': {0: 750, 1: 770, 2: 780, 3: 860, 4: 880},
 'Sodium (% Daily Value)': {0: 31, 1: 32, 2: 33, 3: 36, 4: 37},
 'Carbohydrates': {0: 31, 1: 30, 2: 29, 3: 30, 4: 30},
 'Carbohydrates (% Daily Value)': {0: 10, 1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10},
 'Dietary Fiber': {0: 4, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 4, 4: 4},
 'Dietary Fiber (% Daily Value)': {0: 17, 1: 17, 2: 17, 3: 17, 4: 17},
 'Sugars': {0: 3, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'Protein': {0: 17, 1: 18, 2: 14, 3: 21, 4: 21},
 'Vitamin A (% Daily Value)': {0: 10, 1: 6, 2: 8, 3: 15, 4: 6},
 'Vitamin C (% Daily Value)': {0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0},
 'Calcium (% Daily Value)': {0: 25, 1: 25, 2: 25, 3: 30, 4: 25},
 'Iron (% Daily Value)': {0: 15, 1: 8, 2: 10, 3: 15, 4: 10}}
```

Comment: you forgot to add the data...   https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i mean my "data" is a gigantic csv file how do i add that here

Comment: you can **reduce** it as an example so that users can **replicate** the problem efficiently....

Comment: Try utilizing df.head().to_dict(), that will give us a sample

Comment: Also when trying to formulate  dynamic graphs try using matplotlib

Comment: ok i added the df.head().to_dict(), to my post